# Search Files with VBA (problem, when searching part of the file name)

Tags: excel, vba

in A1:  the file name is listed as "test1"
but the pdf, which I search for is named as test1_  means test1 with an underscore or sometimes this document names test1db.

I use this code, but it didn't copy any data from source to destination folder.
I don't know the exact problem. It reads the value in A1 with test1*  but when it comes to copy the vba code didn't pass the line:

> If objFSO.FileExists(OldPath) Then   objFSO.copyFile OldPath,
> objFSO.BuildPath(strNewPath, strFileToCopy) End If

The full code:

```
Sub copyFile1()
  Dim objFSO As Object, rng As Range
  
Dim strFileToCopy, strOldPath As String, strNewPath As String
  
 
  
  
  strOldPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Source"
  
  
  strNewPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Destination"
  
  With ActiveSheet
  
 
 For Each rng In Range("A1:A2")
 strFileToCopy = rng & "*"
 
   

    
        strFileToCopy = strFileToCopy & ".pdf" 'Suffix anhängen
        
        
    
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        OldPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strOldPath, strFileToCopy)
        
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
OldPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strOldPath, strFileToCopy)
If objFSO.FileExists(OldPath) Then
  objFSO.copyFile OldPath, objFSO.BuildPath(strNewPath, strFileToCopy)
End If

Next

   
   
    
    
  End With
  
  Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a wild card in the destination argument of the [Copy File method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.84)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I do not believe that is an allowable use.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how can I change it?

Comment: Since you are not changing the file name, try just using the folder as the destination argument. See the reference in my previous contact to examine the syntax.